# ImportError: No module named site. Flask + uWSGI +virtualenv

Tags: python, flask, centos, virtualenv, uwsgi

I am having trouble getting my flask app to run on a new server running CentOS 6.5.using uWSGI. (I have a similar CentOS box that it runs fine on)

I installed uWSGI within a virtual environment. I was getting the following error (in `stdout`) when calling uwsgi binary from the virtualenv

`$ /path/to/venv/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals`

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.8 (64bit) on [Mon Nov 17 21:18:13 2014] ***
compiled with version: 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) on 16 November 2014 22:19:09
os: Linux-2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 13 13:06:13 UTC 2013
nodename: boxname
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/username
detected binary path: /home/username/mydevelopment/venvs/ecodev_do/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 1024
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
*** starting uWSGI Emperor ***
*** has_emperor mode detected (fd: 6) ***
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from ers_portal_uwsgi.ini
Mon Nov 17 21:18:14 2014 - [emperor] curse the uwsgi instance ers_portal_uwsgi.ini (pid: 22724)
Mon Nov 17 21:18:17 2014 - [emperor] removed uwsgi instance ers_portal_uwsgi.ini
```

The uwsgi.log file shows:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.8 (64bit) on [Mon Nov 17 21:25:40 2014] ***
compiled with version: 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) on 16 November 2014 22:19:09
os: Linux-2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 13 13:06:13 UTC 2013
nodename: boxname
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/vassals
detected binary path: /home/username/mydevelopment/venvs/ecodev_do/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
chdir() to /home/username/mydevelopment/git/ers_portal
your processes number limit is 1024
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /home/username/mydevelopment/git/ers_portal/ers_portal_uwsgi.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.7.8 (default, Nov 12 2014, 23:36:57)  [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)]
Set PythonHome to /home/username/mydevelopment/venvs/ecovapor_dev
ImportError: No module named site
```

Then, reading the official uWSGI documentation they describe [a scenario](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#install-uwsgi-system-wide) where uwsgi is installed in a venv, but then it has to be installed system-wide after that. So, I used
`pip2.7 install uwsgi` (which created the binary in `/usr/local/bin/uwsgi`)

I have tried all of the following with no change in the error or the output (with and without venv activated)..

1. `$ /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals`
2. `$ /home/username/mydevelopment/venvs/ecodev_do/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals`
3. `$ /home/username/mydevelopment/venvs/ecodev_do/bin/uwsgi --no-site 
   --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals`
4. `$ uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals`
5. `$ uwsgi --no-site --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals`
6. `$ /path/to/venv/bin/uwsgi ~/mydevelopment/git/ers_portal/ers_portal_uwsgi.ini` (the .ini file is symlinked in `/etc/uwsgi/vassals` )

Here is `emperor.ini`;

```
[uwsgi]
emperor = /etc/uwsgi/vassals
uid = username
gid = username
logto = /home/username/mydevelopment/git/ers_portal/logs/uwsgiEmperor.log
```

Here is `ers_portal_uwsgi.ini`;

```
[uwsgi]
master = true
#user info
uid = username
gid = username

#application's base folder
base = /home/username/mydevelopment/git/ers_portal

#chdir to this folder when starting
chdir = /home/username/mydevelopment/git/ers_portal

#python module to import
app = run_web
module = %(app)

home = /home/username/mydevelopment/venvs/ecovapor_dev
pythonpath = %(base)

#socket file's location
socket = /home/username/mydevelopment/git/ers_portal/%n.sock

#permissions for the socket file
chmod-socket    = 666

#the variable that holds a flask application inside the module imported at line #6
#uwsgi varible only, does not relate to your flask application
callable = app

#location of log files
logto = /home/username/mydevelopment/git/ers_portal/logs/%n.log
```

Comment: I've experience this problem before, and, for me, the problem was that uwsgi was running from the root python directory, not my virtualenv. I had to use the absolute directory for my run script.

Comment: @Celeo where do you specify the absolute directory where I am not?

Comment: ensure your virtualenv has been built for the same version used by uWSGI

Comment: @roberto would you mind clarifying your comment? The virtualenv is the same one that runs the app is the same one i pip installed uwsgi to. Forgive me,  i dont understand your comment (built?)

Answer (score 1):

In case someone uses python 3.x, installing uwsgi with pip3 solved this problem for me:

```
sudo pip3 install uwsgi
```

The virtualenv in question and uwsgi must be using the same python version.

In case you want to use multiple python versions on the same system, you can get the uwsgi [source](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi) and follow the instructions here: http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/MultiPython

Then add a "plugin=/path/to/plugin" to the .ini file

Take note that plugins dont work for the packaged Ubuntu versions (built monolithic), but you need to compile the source directly for a fully modular binary

Answer (score 1):

This helped me.
Type it in your terminal.

```
unset PYTHONHOME
unset PYTHONPATH
```